# Js array length increase too early

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a condition based array length. my problem is the array is not increase at the right time.
its hard to explain so i made a plunker and sample code:

When i click on push the second time i want the alert to be 'gt 1'.
How i can solve this problem? maybe with counter or something?

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data">
     <a ng-click="pushUser(user)">push</a>
</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [];

  $scope.data = [{name: 1} ,{name: 2}, {name:3}];

  $scope.pushUser = function(user) {

    if($scope.users.length > 1) {
      alert('gt 1');
      $scope.users.push(user);
    } else {
      alert('lt 1');
      $scope.users.push(user);
    }  
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FsjV20MI0bcwKMqOUOoS?p=preview

Comment: You probably mean *When i click on push the **third** time i want the alert to be 'gt 1'.* and not the **second**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the initial length of array `users` is 0, the condition `if($scope.users.length > 1)` will be evaluated to false, when you click first time. Hence the else part will end up adding an element in the `user` array.

For the second time, when you click the link, the condition `if($scope.users.length > 1)` will still be evaluated to false as the length of array is equal to `1` and not `>1`. So the else part will still get executed and will result in increasing length of `user` array to 2.

Subsequent clicks, will result in displaying alert as `gt 1`. Hence to achieve the desired result, you should change the condition to `if($scope.users.length >= 1)`. Note the operator has been changed to indicate if the array length is greater or equal to one, which is true when you click the link second time.

Answer (score -1):

Push and then check:

```
$scope.users.push(user);

if($scope.users.length => 1) {
  alert('gt 1');      
} else {
  alert('lt 1');
}
```

Comment: I cant i have to do things inside the if and then push.

Comment: if($scope.users.length >= 1) {   -  ?